# Firefox vs Chrome for iMacros

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, imacros

Which browser is better to use iMacros? I prefer the faster running one.

Try to explain it as well. If it's just a quick answer please comment instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use FireFox since I can use JS scripting in FireFox. So far I didn't find a way to use .js files in Chrome.

With pictures disables FireFox can be just as good as Chrome. Also there is some difference in Chrome and FireFox iMacros code. So sometimes FF scripts don't work in Chrome.

Comment: Yeah for some reason, Chrome doesn't work with CLICK command nor the EVENT command. What would be the code for clicking a specific x y coordinate for Chrome? Also, sometimes, for some reason, Firefox seems heavy and slow for commands.

Comment: wiki.imacros.net visit this site and check it out. I am not sure how to reply. You can use CLEAR command co clear cookies from firefox and make it faster. Also if you don't need images you can disable them with FILTER TYPE=IMAGES STATUS=ON

Answer (score 3):

I've found that Firefox is greatly faster with iMacros than Chrome.  I use Chrome for 90% of all my tasks, but when doing something macro-heavy, I use Firefox.