# Imacros Script to call different macros in order

Tags: google-chrome, imacros

I've been searching for a method on how to accomplish this with absolutely no success.

I have 5 separate Macros in my (root) Macros folder for google chrome

[image]

Each example.iim runs a different task with specific timers. Is there a script I can run that will call each Example#.iim script 1 by 1. In the order I choose?

[iimPlay()](http://wiki.imacros.net/iimPlay())

The only thing i've come across is the iimPlay() method. And it simple doesn't work for me. Or more likely, i don't have a clue how to use it or if it's what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

€dit: Apparently this only works for iMacros for Firefox, the Chrome version doesn't seem to support js macros.

iimPlay is one way to go about it, though. Note that iimPlay is to be used from js.

Next to your Example iims, you can create a *foo.js* with the code you want inside, like

```
iimPlay("Example1.iim");
iimPlay("Example2.iim");
iimPlay("Example3.iim");
iimPlay("Example4.iim");
iimPlay("Example5.iim");
```

which will play the iim macros in that order when you play the *foo.js* code.

Comment: How do you crate a js file? If i try to do so in chrome extension window, it says foo.js.iim. If I try to crate the js in windows. Nothing shows up in the root directory in chrome.

Comment: In FF you can right click a file in that view you have in the question and select rename. Just create a new iim macro and rename it to YOURNAME.js. Or you can find the directory where your macros are stored on your hard drive and just create the file there, it should show in your available macros then.

Comment: But this doesn't work for chrome. The .js file does not show up in the window. Can you please test this for yourself?

Comment: It seems iMacros for Chrome does not support js macros... http://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=25172 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/19481414/4563525 . Might want to consider using Firefox instead, if that's an option?